# Visual Studio always rebuilds from scratch when switching from building via MSBuild vs from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I have a C++ project which I build from within Visual Studio. My problem is if I quit Visual Studio and build the same project from the command line via MSBuild.exe, the project is rebuilt from scratch as if *nothing* is up to date, even though no changes are made to any file.

I use the same parameters as within Visual Studio (for example Build/Release/X64).
Note that the same rebuild happens if I build from MSBuild.exe and then build from Visual Studio.

Does anyone know what causes MSBuild to believe that everything is not up to date?

I expect that everything should be up to date when switching from where I build, it was like this some years ago (perhaps in Visual Studio 2019).

Comment: Hmm. Are you using pre-compiled headers? IIRC, where the outputs from them are placed can *potentially* be problematical.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you can chase down where any 'new' intermediate files are being written after both the MSBuild and in-Studio builds. Presumably, they will be in the parent folder, *somewhere*, and a list in order of modification/creation date may shed some light.

Comment: Are VS and MSBuild using the same compiler?

Comment: What about the simplest C++ project, will the issue still exist? On my side, it works fine.

Comment: @AdrianMole Same problem both with and without precompiled headers

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Yes, goes for both simple a large projects

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing `msbuild.exe` to `MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\build.exe` instead of `MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe` when building from the command line.

Notes:

- My build platform target has always been x64
- My CPU is an AMD CPU and I'm not exactly sure what the difference is between the two exe files.